# I got an error when I try to launch Flutter at the first time

Tags: flutter

When I try to launch Flutter in Android Studio or in Visual Code after unpacking it in Disk `C:\` as follows `C:\Flutter`, I get the error `unable to find git in your path` as you can see in [**the following screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwsam.png).

I should point out that when I have already downloaded and installed **Git** on my computer and when I launch flutter doctor in the **CMD** (**Windows**) in *user mode (simple)*, the Terminal closes automatically.

But when I run flutter doctor in the **CMD** (**Windows**) in *Administrator mode*, it returns me [**the following screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHsjy.png).

Please help me to fix this error and make my Flutter installation successful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

***Add Git to your system's PATH:***

**Go to**   *System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables*.

Under "System Variables," find the "Path" variable and click "Edit."
Add the path to your Git installation (usually C:\Program Files\Git\bin and C:\Program Files\Git\cmd) to the list of paths. Make sure each path is separated by a semicolon (;).